# Do ethernet packets remain in linux kernel when traversing two processes in two different network namespace via veth pair?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, virtualization, iptables

I am facing the following situation. We have two network namespaces: ns1 and ns2. They are connected via veth pairs. ns1 is holding ovs and ns2 is holding iptables rules. The packets flow from ovs port 1 to ns2 and go through the iptable checks, and then come back to ns1. The packets are in kernel, and processing is fast.

As the iptables rules grow bigger and bigger, I am thinking we shall separate the ns2 as another os process. The main reason is to use multiple cores on the machine. Connect ns1 holding ovs and ns2 holding iptables rules via veth pair. If I do so, the packets still remain in kernel? And there are no performance penalties like traversing process boundaries, kernel/user space boundaries, multiple copies of the same packets?

I search a bit. Kernel space uses virtual memory like user space. It seems that some region of kernel space is shared by multiple os processes, and is backed up by physical RAM. That is why linux virtual networking is fast. Although namespaces are connected via veth pairs, there are no hardware interrupt involved. I am not sure there are software interrupts involved when packets traverse veth pairs. No matter what as long as the same packet remains in kernel space which is shared by multiple os processes, the performance should be good. Separating iptables namespace into a different process will help in case of multi cores.

Is this understanding correct?